# Some Values Keyframable But Not Present in Dopesheet

Tags: animation, add-on, dopesheet

I'm making another lightsaber movie and this time I'm keyframing the intensity of a lens flare (because the Lens Wizard addon has a couple bugs and I cannot get consistent results with the "Visbility to camera" option)

So anyway, every time there's a clash, I keyframe the intensity value from 0 to about 5.8:

[image]

This works just fine. However, I would love to have control over these keyframes in the Dopesheet or Curves editor. I find it really strange that there are no keyframes that show up on either. What's even weirder is if I keyframe a different value, like the color, it shows up:
[image]

Any ideas on why this might be or how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: what does your curve editor looklike?

Comment: @FacebFaceb It has all the same values as the dope sheet. Would you like me to post a picture?